# delete duplicates and sorts output

Tags: python, sorting

would anyone help me to solve this?
I have this code, they need the calculations to sort from the largest to the largest (first numbers) and then to eliminate duplications
i know i should use .sort ()
but I'm clueless who I do

for these results

```
5=1=1
5=1=1
1=1=5
1=5=1
1=1=5
1=5=1
4=2=1
4=1=2
2=1=4
2=4=1
1=2=4
1=4=2
3=3=1
3=1=3
3=1=3
3=3=1
1=3=3
1=3=3
3=2=2
3=2=2
2=2=3
2=3=2
2=2=3
2=3=2
```

output inline thos I want this to do

```
1=1=5
1=2=4
1=3=3
1=4=2
1=5=1
2=1=4
2=2=3
2=3=2
2=4=1
3=1=3
3=2=2
3=3=1
4=1=2
4=2=1
5=1=1
```

code

```py
def part(n, k):
    def _part(n, k, pre):
        if n <= 0:
            return []
        if k == 1:
            if n <= pre:
                return [[n]]
            return []
        ret = []
        for i in range(min(pre, n), 0, -1):
            ret += [[i] + sub for sub in _part(n-i, k-1, i)]
        return ret
    return _part(n, k, n)
x = part(7,3)
for i in x:
   print(str(i[0])+'='+str(i[1])+'='+str(i[2]))
   print(str(i[0])+'='+str(i[2])+'='+str(i[1]))
   print(str(i[1])+'='+str(i[2])+'='+str(i[0]))
   print(str(i[1])+'='+str(i[0])+'='+str(i[2]))
   print(str(i[2])+'='+str(i[1])+'='+str(i[0]))
   print(str(i[2])+'='+str(i[0])+'='+str(i[1]))
```

Comment: I would like to ask you to edit the whole code thank you I tried to add those two options but it's beyond my knowledge thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard list sorting will work on this.
To remove dupes, convert to set and back to list.

---

**EDIT**
So, slight editing of your last for loop. For readability I advise to use a so-called f-string.
I misunderstood your question due to the original code formatting, but this short example should work on the result of your function...

```py
lst = []
for elem in x:
   lst.append(f"{elem[0]}={elem[1]}={elem[2]}")
   lst.append(f"{elem[0]}={elem[2]}={elem[1]}")
   lst.append(f"{elem[1]}={elem[0]}={elem[2]}")
   lst.append(f"{elem[1]}={elem[2]}={elem[0]}")
   lst.append(f"{elem[2]}={elem[0]}={elem[1]}")
   lst.append(f"{elem[2]}={elem[1]}={elem[0]}")

lst = sorted(list(set(lst)))
for elem in lst:
    print(elem)
```

output

```
1=1=5
1=2=4
1=3=3
1=4=2
1=5=1
2=1=4
2=2=3
2=3=2
2=4=1
3=1=3
3=2=2
3=3=1
4=1=2
4=2=1
5=1=1
```

Comment: can i ask for a remake? on my script? thanx

Comment: boužel doesn't work because I don't know how to work with it here in python and I don't know how to print all the data into one and let it work with it

Comment: can you fix your indentation? I tried fixing it but it's not correct. See [this formatting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) on how to properly format code in your question. In short, put it between \`\`\`

Comment: completed thanx for hellp

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

```
set_data_str = """5=1=1
5=1=1
1=1=5
1=5=1
1=1=5
1=5=1
4=2=1
4=1=2
2=1=4
2=4=1
1=2=4
1=4=2
3=3=1
3=1=3
3=1=3
3=3=1
1=3=3
1=3=3
3=2=2
3=2=2
2=2=3
2=3=2
2=2=3
2=3=2"""

# break the string into a list on the new lines
# create a set from the list
set_data = set(set_data_str.split('\n'))

# sort the set into a list
sorted_set_data = sorted(set_data)

# convert the sorted list into a string to print it
print('\n'.join(sorted_set_data))
```

Credit to @Edo-Akse for better formatting

Comment: can i ask for a remake? on my script? thanx

Comment: boužel doesn't work because I don't know how to work with it here in python and I don't know how to print all the data into one and let it work with it